# Regex redirection in .httaccess to fix 404 error pages

Tags: regex

My site has been hacked and made thousands of 404 pages in sitemaps
as following

```
b3cyuYwa1118f55kst722ac22
e09nfzNa1116640bGy31c6187
3f4CiVUa11110c0GwJ1341740
1ebDkisa1118971VPY819e0eb
bb1rRena1110a5eZws36debc8
```

i noticed that all of them has `111` number in the middle

so, how to make a redirection in .httacess file to redirect all these pages to one page in my site using Regex  to match as following

```
example.com/(any number)(any letter)111(any number)(any letter)
```

Answer (score 0):

`.htaccess` uses `PCRE`, so, you can try with this regex

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]+?111[a-zA-Z0-9]+$
```

take a look [here](https://regex101.com/r/NUu1qi/1)

In your `.htaccess`, try with this:

```
RewriteRule "^[a-zA-Z0-9]+?111[a-zA-Z0-9]+$" "URL_of_desired_page_here"
```

Comment: i add this line to the top of .httaccess but it didn't work
`RewriteRule ^[a-zA-Z0-9]+?111[a-zA-Z0-9]+$ http://example.com/page/`

also i tried this but it didn't work too
`RewriteRule ^[a-zA-Z0-9]+?111[a-zA-Z0-9]+$ [NC,R=410,L]`

Comment: i found the issue, 410 template wasn't enabled in the cpanel - to enable it just add `ErrorDocument 410 default` in .htaccess